Integrating $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \exp\left(A\sin^{2}\phi +B\cos^{2}\phi+a\sin\phi +b\cos\phi\right) {\rm d}\phi$
I am looking for the following nice looking but hard to manage integral:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{A\sin^{2}\phi +B\cos^{2}\phi+a\sin\phi +b\cos\phi} {\rm d}\phi \tag{A}, $$
and specifically I want to to express it in closed form, which I believe will be in terms of the Modified Bessel function of first kind. (Its definition is given by $I_{0}(x):=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{x\cos\phi}{\rm d}\phi.) $
After some elaboration, I found that the integral in $(A)$ equals
$$e^{\frac{A+B}{2}}\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{k\cos(2\phi)+l\sin(\phi+c)}{\rm d}\phi \tag{B}$$
where $k=\frac{B-A}{2}, l=\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}, c=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}} \right)$.
But I am stuck on how to proceed with any of the two integrals.
I also used the "Arbitrary Phase Shift Formula" and I wrote the power of the exponent as $p \cos\left(\phi+\xi-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ where $p:=\pm \sqrt{|k^{2}+l^{2}+2k l \cos(\phi+c+\pi/2)|}$, and $\xi:=\tan^{-1}\left( \frac{k\sin(\phi+\pi/2)+l\sin(-c)}{k\cos(\phi+\pi/2)+l\cos(-c)}\right)$, but I am not sure if that's useful.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Mathematica does not give a general form (at least my attempts using Mathematica).  But if $A=B$, then equation (A) is $2 \pi  e^A I_0\left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\right)$ which is of the form you suggested.  There are likely other special cases with a closed form.

If $a=b=0$, then the integral is $2 \pi  e^{\frac{A+B}{2}} I_0\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)$.
